# How to animate scrollLeft?

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

does anyone know how to modify this code, so it will animate a slide effect?

```
$('.carouselNext').click(function() {
    var pos = $('.carouselOut').scrollLeft() + 192;
    $('.carouselOut').scrollLeft(pos);
});
```

I hope someone can help me :)

Comment: Do you have any error? What problem are you facing? What is happening and what are you expecting?

Comment: the animate marginleft, is not working, when the div is no longer it just keeps going on and on...

Comment: there is no problems, well the only problem is, don't know hos to make it animate scrollLeft.. :/